# Can't use parentheses keys in VMWare 9.0

Tags: keyboard, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a rather urgent problem. I can't use the parentheses keys in VMWare. I was using Windows 8 as a guest at the time. I got a warning about sticky keys. I of course click the don't enable and made sure that all of those features are disabled. But, now I can't use `(` or `)`. When I go to use them (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>) nothing happens. I can enter in `*` and all of the other keys requiring Shift with one exception - when I try to use `<` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) I instead get `|` and without Shift I still get `,`.

It seems like it somehow changed to a subtly different keyboard layout, but that doesn't appear to be the case as far as I can tell. What would cause this extremely weird problem!?

I'm using a standard US keyboard

Comment: This sounds like a physical problem with the keyboard.  Replace the keyboard.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not. I'm doing this in a virtual machine. On the host machine the keys work fine

Comment: What version of Windows 8 is this? Developer preview? It might be a bug.

Comment: @AceLegend Enterprise (release version? Whatever latest is available through msdn). Also, I tried rebooting the virtual machine and that didn't do anything

Comment: I just checked. It's a release preview. It is possible that it is a bug. Although I doubt it. What virtualization software are you using?

Comment: Check if the On-Screen keyboard shows you the layout you have.

Comment: @Luciano the on-screen layout is significantly different(it's suppose to be for ease of touch screen use).

Comment: @AceLegend no, it's a full release. I believe there is also a free release preview, but I have the one requiring an MSDN subscription. In System under control panel there is no reference to it being a release candidate, and it's activated. I'm using VMWare 9.0 with tools installed. The host machine is Arch Linux. Keyboard still works fine on the host machine

Comment: Alright. But what virtualization software are you using?

Comment: Also, before this happened, I was just typing. Parentheses was working fine, then a sticky keys message came up, and now they don't work

Comment: Alright. I am almost positive this might be a bug. Sticky Keys probably did something to alter the keyboard. You could try going to control panel and resetting the keyboard layout. Also, attaching an external keyboard might fix the problem temporarily.

Comment: @AceLegend Found out it's a VMWare problem. Affects VMs other than Windows 8

Comment: Alright. Well, I can't help you any more then. I use virtual box. Good luck!

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?  I am having the exact same problem with a Win7 guest system running in Vmware Player 5.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.  Every key works except for left and right parenthesis.

Comment: I can't remember how I fixed this unfortunately, but I did